# issubclass(typing.List, list) raises TypeError

Tags: python-3.x, annotations, python-typing

`typing.List` is defined as `class typing.List(list, MutableSequence[T])` in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/typing.html?highlight=typing#typing.List), which should mean it's a subclass of `list`, but `issubclass()` seems confused about it:

`issubclass(typing.List, typing.List)` returns **True**, confirming `typing.List` is a class.

But `issubclass(typing.List, list)` raises **TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class**, indicating the opposite!

To complete the confusion, `issubclass(list, typing.List)` returns **True**.

I understand it's far more likely that I've misunderstood something than that core library functions are broken, but I'd love to be told why!

This is Python 3.8.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `typing.List` is defined as `class typing.List(list, MutableSequence[T])`

Yes and not. I think this should rather describe the behavior, but it's not implemented in this way.

Take a look in the cpython source-code how [List is defined](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4844abdd700120120fc76c29d911bcb547700baf/Lib/typing.py#L1478). It's an instance of [`_GenericAlias`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4844abdd700120120fc76c29d911bcb547700baf/Lib/typing.py#L650). 
You can also find this out if you use `type()`:

```py
>>> type(typing.List)
<class 'typing._GenericAlias'>
```

You can see this class has implemented the [magic method `__subclasscheck__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4844abdd700120120fc76c29d911bcb547700baf/Lib/typing.py#L771-L778). For further reference I've copied/cite these lines from the cpython repo:

```py
def __subclasscheck__(self, cls):
    if self._special:
        if not isinstance(cls, _GenericAlias):
            return issubclass(cls, self.__origin__)
        if cls._special:
            return issubclass(cls.__origin__, self.__origin__)
    raise TypeError("Subscripted generics cannot be used with"
                    " class and instance checks")
```

---

When you now call `issubclass(typing.List, typing.List)`, python call this method and because both arguments are instances of `_GenericAlias` and special (`._special = True`) the method will enter this branch: `return issubclass(cls.__origin__, self.__origin__)`. 
`self__origin__` is the Built-in Type `list`.
So the call `issubclass(typing.List, typing.List)` is in the end the call `issubclass(list, list)`. That means you check not really `typing.List` ifself, but the representing built-in type.

When you call `issubclass(typing.List, list)` the branch `return issubclass(cls, self.__origin__)` will be entered (because the argument `cls` is `list` and this is not an instance of `_GenericAlias`). Therefor it's again the same result as `issubclass(list, list)`.

With `issubclass(typing.List, list)` you call `list`'s `__subclasscheck__` method (the call is aquivalent to `list.__subclasscheck__(typing.List)`). 
This fails now because subclass-checks need two arguments that are classes, not instances. But `typing.List` is an instance of `_GenericAlias` and not a class. So this fails with a `TypeError`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this, and destroying my naive belief in `issubclass() :)